# Передача информации с Combobox

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox

Мне  нужно  передавать информацию(1) (что я выбрал  в комбобоксе в свою функцию) а потом  результат функции записываю в Edit (2). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 Но почемуто не  записывается в Edit((
Код :

```
 hEndVertexStatic = CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"End Vertex:",
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
    695, 150, 80, 20,
    hWnd, (HMENU)ID_END_VERTEX_STATIC, 
    hInst, NULL);

hEndVertexCombo = CreateWindowW(L"Combobox", NULL,
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_DROPDOWN,
    770, 150, 120, 110, hWnd, NULL, 
    hInst, NULL);
................................

if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)
{
    SendMessage(hStartVertexCombo, CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, (WPARAM)TRUE, 0);
    return;
}

if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)
{
    SendMessage(hEndVertexCombo, CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, (WPARAM)TRUE, 0);
    return;
}

if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_FIND_PATH_BUTTON)
{
            /* тут я вызываю свою функцию*/
    FindPath(hWnd);
    return;
}

if (HIWORD(wParam) == ID_FILE_PATH_EDIT)
{
              /* тут  должен результат вывести моей функции FindPath*/
    SendMessage(hFoundPathEdit, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, (WPARAM)TRUE, 0);
    return;
}
    .......................
for (const Vector& vertex : vertexBuffer)
{
..........................................................................
   SendMessage(hStartVertexCombo, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)vertexStr.c_str());
        SendMessage(hEndVertexCombo, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)vertexStr.c_str());
}
 ...................

void FindPath(HWND hWnd)
{
     int iStartVertex = (int)SendMessage(hStartVertexCombo, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
     int iEndVertex = (int)SendMessage(hEndVertexCombo, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);

     auto findPath = findShortestPath(graph, iStartVertex, iEndVertex);
     Path vector = std::move(findPath.first);
     for (VertexIndex index = 0; index < vector.size(); ++index)
     {
      .............................................
         SendMessage(hFoundPathEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)vertexStr.c_str());
    //SetWindowText(hFoundPathEdit, vertexStr.c_str());
     }
}
```

UPD: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как у вас обработчик `CBN_SELCHANGE` выгялдит?

Comment: @VTT у меня  нету  его.

Comment: @VTT я не использую CBN_SELCHANGE

Comment: Ну так используйте, это оповещение как раз приходит, когда значение к комбобоксе изменяется. Или тут надо только по нажатию кнопки реагировать? `SendMessage(hEndVertexCombo, CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` неправильно, так как второй параметр должен быть идентификатором сообщения.

Comment: @VTT только по нажатию кнопки реагировать. А что вместо CBS_DROPDOWNLIST использовать чтобы  работало?

Comment: Не знаю, тут совершенно непонятно, что этот вызов должен был делать... И не особо понятно в чем проблема. `FindPath` у вас вызывается.

Comment: @VVT Еще раз. Я  задаю вертексы . В функции  FindPath  я  передаю индексы выбраных Vertex  в  функцию auto findResult = findShortestPath(graph, iStartVertex, iEndVertex); И результат этой функции мне нужно вывести в Edit(2)  что я  и  дилаю - SetWindowText(hFoundPathEdit, vertexStr.c_str());

Comment: И что из этого не работает?

Comment: @VVT так  не выводится результат

Comment: @VVT прошел  дебагом. Не  заходит в функцию FindPath;

Comment: Может это потому что обработчики нажатия на кнопку срабатывают выше? После `if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)` надо еще идентификатор контрола проверять. А то так до `if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_FIND_PATH_BUTTON)` может и не доходить.

Comment: @VTT  надо еще идентификатор контрола проверят - можете пример навести?

Comment: Так вот же проверка `(LOWORD(wParam) == ID_FIND_PATH_BUTTON)`

Comment: @VVT так я там и вызываю функцию FindPath(hWnd); Или там нужно делать SendMessage? Я SendMessage  делаю в

Comment: if (HIWORD(wParam) == ID_FILE_PATH_EDIT)
    {
  SendMessage(hFoundPathEdit, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, (WPARAM)TRUE, 0);
  return;
 } куда мне  нужно  результат віводить

Comment: Но проверять-то надо реньше, иначе при нажатии на кнопку будет срабатывать первый обработчик `if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)`

Comment: @VTT перенес наперед. Выводит значения которое я выбрал в втором комбобоксе. а не результат функции. какаята чертовня))

Comment: @VTT выложил скрин в UPD

Comment: @VTT я  тут подумал. может у меня  с пустое 0 значение. поэтому и не  работает моя функция. Я как сделать что бы всегда было что-то выбрано,  сразу после заполнения списков принудительно выбирают начальные значения?

Comment: @VTT нет  проверил индесы, индексы нормальные, и правильно указывают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы отправляете собщение WM_SETTEXT элементу EDITBOX в каждой итерации цикла.
Но это сообщение устанавливает в EDITBOX новую строку (а не дописывает ее к уже существующему тексту). Поэтому все выводы в окно подобным образом до последнего прохода по телу цикла не имеют смысла - в окошке все равно будет только последняя строка. Если Вы хотите дописывать новые строки в EDITBOX в каждом проходе цикла, используйте пару сообщений [EM_SETSEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (переместить каретку в конец текста) и [EM_REPLACESEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (заменить пустое выделение новым текстом т.е. добавить новую строку в конец существующего текста).